# Tkinter listbox get attribute error

Tags: python, tkinter

Been banging my head against a wall with this one. Just getting the ropes of Tkinter, followed a tutorial to get the basics, now working forward to implement my own stuff. I creating a query interface for some work I'm doing. I have three list boxes on screen, and I need to get the selections from all three on button click, so I can generate a query and display some data.

The error I'm receiving seems to say it can't see `mapLBox`, indicating a scope problem. If I change the code to something simple like `print self.mapLBox.get(Tkinter.ACTIVE)` it will still throw the same attribute error. All boxes and scrollbars draw correctly to the screen, and with the erroneous line (#90) commented out, it runs fine.

There are two classes, `simpleApp_tk` ([PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/TEuahMY5)), which all the below code belongs to, and `dbtools` which runs queries on the DB and returns results.

The error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1473, in __call__
         return self.func(*args)
    File "test.py", line 90, in OnButtonClick
         self.labelVar.set(self.mapLBox.get(self.mapLBox.curselection()[0]))
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1829, in __getattr__
         return getattr(self.tk, attr)
AttributeError: mapLBox
```

Inside my `initialise` method (run from `__init__`) the lists and button are created:

```
button = Tkinter.Button(self,text=u"Click Me",command=self.OnButtonClick)
button.grid(column=1,row=0)

# Make a scrollbar for the maps list
scrollbar2 = Tkinter.Scrollbar(self,orient=Tkinter.VERTICAL)
scrollbar2.grid(column=2,row=2,sticky='EW')

# Create list of maps
mapLBox = Tkinter.Listbox(self,selectmode=Tkinter.SINGLE,exportselection=0, yscrollcommand=scrollbar2.set)
scrollbar2.config(command=mapLBox.yview)
mapLBox.grid(column=2,row=2,sticky='EW')

# Populate map list
nameList = self.db.getMapNameList()
IDList = self.db.getMapIDList()
for count, name in enumerate(nameList):
    nameFormat = str(IDList[count][0])+': '+name[0]
        mapLBox.insert(Tkinter.END,nameFormat)

self.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight=1) # Allow resizing of window
self.resizable(True,True) # Contrain to only horizontal
self.update()
self.geometry(self.geometry())
```

The `OnButtonClick` method attached to my button:

```
def OnButtonClick(self):
    self.labelVar.set(self.mapLBox.get(self.mapLBox.curselection()[0]))
    return
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are accessing `self.mapLBox` but you aren't defining `self.mapLBox`. Just because you create  variable named `mapLBox` doesn't mean it automatically becomes an attribute of the object.

You need to change this:

```
mapLBox = Tkinter.Listbox(...)
```

... to this:

```
self.mapLBox = Tkinter.Listbox(...)
```

... and, of course, change the other places where you reference `mapLBox`.

Comment: An obvious one, how did I miss that! Thanks!